# Use code in DLL from the loading binary

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, dll, shared-libraries

I am currently trying to use the **QPluginLoader** of Qt to build a **plugin system**. In my plugin, which I will compile as a DLL (.so), I need to use some classes which are compiled into the main binary (which will load the plugin).

This does not work, because the loading at runtime through the **QPluginLoader** will fail with the error message: *Cannot load library ... plugin.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol ...*

So the symbols are actually in my main binary and I want to use them in my DLL... But why are these symbols not available to the DLL? Is it possible to achieve this somehow? (Some magic compile flag hopefully..)

*Note:* I could compile the sources of main program into my DLL, but this just sounds stupid when building a **plugin system**!

Comment: A `.so` is a shared object, not a DLL.

Comment: shared object or dynamic link library - who cares? Two names for the same thing. In this case I compiled under Linux, if I would compile under Windows it would have a .dll extension.

Comment: No, read [Drepper's paper: How To Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). You'll understand that `.so` are *not* DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile flag **-export-dynamic** will solve this problem. Here is the description from the gcc documentation:

> Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of dlopen or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.